# git add failing because of .DS_STORE file

Tags: git-add

I removed a .DS_STORE file from my local repo then I ran git add ., and I have this message :

```
fatal: unable to stat '.DS_Store': No such file or directory
```

How can I manage this ?

Comment: Try `git rm -r --cached .DS_Store` and then `git add -A`?

Comment: Also add `.DS_STORE` to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: thank you both in fact I simply ran git rm .DS_STORE and I totlally forgot to put the file in my .gitignore